# How to print certain text to a user from an API response

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Sorry if the title is hard to understand. I have an API that gives me stock info but I only want certain text to show to the user.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo')
print(response.text)
```

This returns the stocks for Microsoft, it resets every week or so and gives a new reading every 5 minutes. If you run the code or just use common logic, you will see/know that there is a lot of information. Let`s say that I want to just get the last time the API refreshed (number 3) and just show that to the user:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-12-09 16:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Parse the JSON (requests has a method to do that for you) and manipulate the resulting dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by jonrsharpe you need to parse the response into JSON and then just pick out the key you're looking for:

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo')
my_json = json.loads(response.text)
print(my_json["Meta Data"])
```

If your question is to specifically only pull the "Meta Data" field from the API and not the whole response, you won't be able to unless the API provides that functionality

EDIT: As stated by  Petru Tanas you can also use response.json() instead of importing the json module:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=5min&apikey=demo')
my_json = response.json()
print(my_json["Meta Data"])
```

Comment: response object already has json() method. You could use that directly.